# When positioning an image in a <div>

Tags: css

Would there be an advantage to using percentages over words to position said image?  For example in a CSS file:

```
#example_1 {
  background: url();
  background-position: 50% 50%;
}

#example_2 {
  background: url();
  background-position: center;
}
```

While both effectively center the image.  Would there be a case where one would be more "correct"?

Answer (score 0):

There is no difference between `center center` and `50% 50%`.
`background-position: center center;` is the popular solution.

Comment: Thank you for the response.